# Data is being added infinitely or it does not stop being added, how to prevent this? PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am having a trouble when adding data to my database, what is happening is it is adding infinitely or non stop. I have already tried using the `break` but still the problem keeps existing. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
foreach ($csvData as $key => $value) {                      
        if(isset($studentIDFromDB[$value['studentID']])){
            $updateFields[$key] = array(                                
                'studentID'             => $value['studentID'],
                'programType'           => $value['programType'],
            );
        }else{
            $insertFields[$key] = array(
                'studentID'             => $value['studentID'],
                'programType'           => $value['programType'],                           
            );
        }
}

if(isset($updateFields)){
    $chunk1 = array_chunk($updateFields,100);
        for($i=0;$i < count($chunk1);$i++) {
            $this->DBLogic->updateBatchRecordMultipleConditionz($chunk1[$i]);
            $this->DBLogic->addBatchRecord('tbl_tt_academicinfo', $updateFields);
            break;
         }
}
```

Comment: what is the total count of $updateFields

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you call "addBatchRecord" with every iteration and you pass "updateFields" as value. How many entries does it contain? It gets called count($updateFields) / 100 (chunk size) times.

```
for($i=0;$i < count($chunk1);$i++) {
    $this->DBLogic->updateBatchRecordMultipleConditionz($chunk1[$i]);
    $this->DBLogic->addBatchRecord('tbl_tt_academicinfo', $chunk1[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Hello, is there any chance that I can include `$updateFields` in the parameter? I need the updateFields for my data though, the data does not add when I replace it with `$chunk1[$i]` only.

Comment: should I also remove the `break` ?

Comment: If you remove the break you only will process 100 entries (the chunk size). What is happening inside addBatchRecord?

Comment: Giler - Hello sir, addBatchRecord insert batch data.

Comment: `public function addBatchRecord($table, $fields){
  $this->db->insert_batch($table, $fields);
 }`

Comment: Can you update your question to contain a part of "var_dump($updateFields)"?